# Handle specific input

Tags: c#

Ok I'm doing a univerity C# assignment that involves an animal motel...

I'll skip the details and cut to the chase..I'm havin problems with the input..I'm not sure how to handle the specific animal input like wingspan for birds, number of teeths for mammals?
this is a chunk of the code from my mainform class:

```
private void AddAnimal(){

    Animal animalObj;

    Category animalCategory = (Category)CategoryList.SelectedIndex;

    switch (animalCategory)
    {
        case Category.Mammal:
            MammalSpecies animalSpecies = (MammalSpecies)Enum.Parse(typeof (MammalSpecies), AnimalList.Text);
            animalObj = MammalFactory.CreateMammal(animalSpecies);
         break;
    }
}
```

I was thinking of something like this:

```
animalObj.name = txtName.Text;
```

but realised I cant handle the specific animal input like this only the general like name age etc..

Comment: That seems fine, what's the problem? Do you need to do some parsing to the other fields? Can you elaborate on what needs to be done on the other fields?

Comment: I'm havin trouble parsing the input for the speciel characteristics for each animal...like wingspan for birds and number of teeth for mammals.

Comment: Do you mean you don't know how to parse integer values?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, what I meant was I have no problems parsing the values..It's more of an issue using them when creating the object..normnally I wouldn't have a problem with it but because of the derived classes I'm confused..And my tutor is just confusing my with pseudo code which I cant wrap my head around

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure if I understand your question, but here goes. I asume that you have problems setting up the stats for each animal, so that a non flying animal won't have wings. I suggest, that you create an animal super class, with all the general data/functionality and then create a sub class for each animal.

Here is an example of the animal class. This is the super class of all animals:

```
/// <summary>
/// This is an enum, that defines the different species of animals
/// </summary>
enum Species {Mammal, Fish, Insect, Bird}

/// <summary>
/// This is the base class for all animals
/// The class is abstract, so that we cant instantiated (Animal a = new Animal() is no longer possible)
/// It wouldn't make any sense to instantiate an animal (what color does and animal have, how many legs etc....) thats why its abstract
/// </summary>
abstract class Animal
{
    /// <summary>
    /// All animals has teeth, so we add this field to the animal
    /// </summary>
    private int teeth;

    /// <summary>
    /// All animals have legs, so we add this field in the animal as well
    /// </summary>
    private int legs;

    /// <summary>
    /// I'm not 100% sure about how the species should work
    /// I just implemented and enum for 3 species
    /// This can be adapted to suit your needs
    /// </summary>
    private Species species;

    /// <summary>
    /// This is the constructor of the animal. this constructor takes in 
    /// all the base values of the animal
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="species">The current animals species</param>
    /// <param name="legs">The current animal's amount of legs</param>
    /// <param name="teeth">The current animal's amount of theeth</param>
    public Animal(Species species, int legs, int teeth)
    {
        //Sets the number of teeth on the current animal
        this.teeth = teeth;

        //Sets the number of legs on the current animal
        this.legs = legs;

        //Sets the species of the current animal
        this.species = species;
    }
}
```

This is an example of a sub class. In this case its a duck, as you can see it adds a wingspand to the animal:

```
/// <summary>
/// This is a duck class, it inherits from the Animal class
/// Inheritance is done in C# by using Class A : Class B
/// The point of inheritance is to pass on members and functionality from a superclass to a sub class
/// In this case we give the duck legs, teeth and a species
/// </summary>
class Duck : Animal
{
    private int wingSpan;

    /// <summary>
    /// This is the constructor of the Duck subclass
    /// It takes in all the parameters that the super class needs +wingSpan
    /// It passes on the superclass parameters to the Animal class by calling the super class constructer with the
    /// Keyword base()
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="wingSpan">The duck's wingspan</param>
    /// <param name="species">The species of the duck</param>
    /// <param name="legs">The amount of legs of the duck</param>
    /// <param name="teeth">The duck's amount of teeth</param>
    public Duck(int wingSpan, Species species, int legs, int teeth) : base(species,legs,teeth)
    {
        //sets the ducks number of wings
        this.wingSpan = wingSpan;
    }
}
```

This is how you can create a duck inside add animal:

```
 //Instantiates a duck
 Duck duck = new Duck(2, Species.Bird, 2, 0);
```

Comment: I haven't really gotten to the concept of abstract classes but yeas I'm having problems setting the stats for the specific characterisitcs of each animal like wingspan for birds and number of teeth for mammals.

I have a super class Animal with two sub classes mammal and bird which also have two derived classes cat and dog, eagle and falcon.

It's more like problems when I want to create the animal.I understand how to set the name, age, length but the special ones are a bit more troublesome...I'm still a newb in C# lol

Comment: Can you give an example of what you have a problem with?

Comment: Alright lets say I want to create the animal with the code I gave in the original question..Normally I would do it like you suggested:

Duck duck = new Duck(2, Species.Bird, 2, 0);

But because I have like special traits for different animals i.e wingspan for birds I'm not sure how to do it?

Comment: Then you shuld be able to use the structure I gave you. In my structure only ducks will have wings.